# How to detect logstash input connection error

Tags: logstash

How can I monitor and detect errors when connecting kafka to logstash.

Say for example my kafka broker is down and no connection is established between kafka and logstash.

Is there a way in to get the monitor the connection status between logstash and kafka?
I can query logstash logs (but I don't think it is the appropriate way) and I tried to use logstash monitoring API (for example localhost:9600/_node/stats/pipelines?pretty) but no api gives me the connection status is off

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have an `elastic agent` or a `metricbeat agent` installed on the Kafka node, you can configure the agent to monitor them using their Kafka specific module.

- [elastic-agent kafka module](https://docs.elastic.co/en/integrations/kafka)
- [metricbeat kafka module](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/metricbeat/current/metricbeat-module-kafka.html)

For getting the connection status from logstash as you mentioned, you can also configure your logstash config to grab the status from the log message.

Sample document in elasticsearch :

```
{
    "_index": "topicname",
    "_type": "_doc",
    "_id": "ulF8uH0BK9MbBSR7DPEw",
    "_version": 1,
    "_score": null,
    "fields": {
      "@timestamp": [
        "2022-05-09T10:27:56.956Z"
            ],
        "@version": [
            "1"
        ],
        "@version.keyword": [
            "1"
        ],
        "message": [
            "{\"requestMethod\":\"GET\",\"headers\":{\"content-type\":\"application/json\",\"user-agent\":\"PostmanRuntime/7.XX.XX\",\"accept\":\"*/*\",\"postman-token\":\"11224442345223\",\"host\":\"localhost:2300\",\"accept-encoding\":\"gzip, deflate, br\",\"connection\":\"keep-alive\",\"content-length\":\"44\"},\"body\":{\"category\":\"CAT\",\"noise\":\"purr\"},\"query\":{},\"requestUrl\":\"http://localhost:2300/kafka\",\"protocol\":\"HTTP/1.1\",\"remoteIp\":\"1\",\"requestSize\":302,\"userAgent\":\"PostmanRuntime/7.XX.X\",\"statusCode\":200,\"response\":{\"success\":true,\"message\":\"Kafka Details are added\",\"data\":{\"kafkaData\":{\"_id\":\"12gvsddwqbwrfteacr313rcet5\",\"category\":\"DOG\",\"noise\":\"bark\",\"__v\":0},\"postData\":{\"category\":\"DOG\",\"noise\":\"bark\"}}},\"latency\":{\"seconds\":0,\"nanos\":61000000},\"responseSize\":193}"
        ]
    } }
```

Below configuration can be added to fetch the status:

```
  input {
    kafka {
      topics => ["topicname"]
      bootstrap_servers => "11.11.11.11:1111"
    }
  }
  
  filter{
        mutate { add_field => { "StatusCode" => "%{[message][0][status]}" } }
  }
  
  output {
   elasticsearch {
      hosts => ["11.11.11.12:9200"]
      index => "topic-name-index"
   }
  }
```

Comment: but what if my kafka brokers are not in my hand, that is are deployed by other party or organization and I only send message to it? How can I tell via logstash that it was able to connect and send event to it?